# simple API to handle HTTP Request from go apps with and without Concurrent (Go Routine)

Tags: go, http, goroutine

just come back to golang to try the concurrent programming, i try using concurrent for fetching 10 datas from my simple apps running in my localhost

so first i made a simple apps with Gin

```
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.JSON(200, map[string]string{
            "msg": "hae",
        })
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":9090", r)
}
```

and then, i make 2 program to fetch datas with and without using concurrent
without:

```
func main() {
    t := time.Now()

    // 10 request without concurrent
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fetchWithout()
    fmt.Println("total time", time.Since(t))
}

func fetchWithout() {
    t := time.Now()

    c, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 50*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    url := "http://localhost:9090/"
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(c, "GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
}
```

with:

```
func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    ch := make(chan string, 10)
    ctx := context.Background()

    var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(10)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)
    go fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx, ch, wg)

    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)

    fmt.Println(len(ch))

    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

    fmt.Println("total time", time.Since(t))
}

func fetchWithGoRoutine(ctx context.Context, ch chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    t := time.Now()

    c, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 50*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    url := "http://localhost:9090/"
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(c, "GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return err
    }
    ch <- string(body)

    wg.Done()
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
    return nil
}
```

from fetch without go routine i got this result:

```
{"msg":"hae"}
1.500143ms
{"msg":"hae"}
424.638µs
{"msg":"hae"}
469.86µs
{"msg":"hae"}
306.838µs
{"msg":"hae"}
226.128µs
{"msg":"hae"}
190.87µs
{"msg":"hae"}
181.057µs
{"msg":"hae"}
187.185µs
{"msg":"hae"}
240.558µs
{"msg":"hae"}
209.465µs
total time 4.042698ms
```

see the result first take 1.500143ms
and for the next result take shorter and shorter time

now from fetching with go routine i got this result:

```
2.108271ms
2.131273ms
2.462516ms
2.584931ms
2.529166ms
2.518011ms
2.618236ms
2.639384ms
2.863897ms
3.264948ms
10
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
{"msg":"hae"}
total time 3.542049ms
```

see the result here, i got about 2-3ms for each request.

the question is, why if i use go routine to http.request i got a longer response time for each request than the simple synchronous http.request?????

Comment: Note that your total time is smaller. Also, the sequential version has a chance to reuse a single open connection whereas the concurrent one probably needs more connections. This is evident from the durations, in the sequential version the first call takes the longest time.